# how to do with a request which needs to take a long time to run?

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django to develop a classifier service, and user can build a model using api like `http://localhost/api/buildmodel`, however, because building a model takes a long time, maybe 2 hours, and I'm using web page to show the result of building a model. How to design my Django program to return immediately and do something to show the result after building finish? maybe I can use ajax but I want to implement it in Python, like using a async method and calling a callback function after building, any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a task queue manager. [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) is by far the most popular task manager for Django. The idea is that you give a task to this manager, then it processes the task and once it is done, it can fire a callback function. Within the callback function, you can you run your logic to notify the user that the task has been completed.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to create a row in a persistent database (or a redis key/value pair) for the task which says if it is running or finished. Have the code set the value to be running when the task starts and done when the task completes. Then have an AJAX call do a GET lookup on a URL that sends the status for the task via a web service. You can put that in a setInterval() to periodically poll the database to see if it is done. You could send an email on completion or just have a landing page / dashboard that shows the status of the tasks being run.